# React router - undefined history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I am trying to use the 1.0.0-rc1 react-router and history 2.0.0-rc1 to navigate manually through the website after pressing the button. Unfortunately, after pressing the button I get:

> Cannot read property 'pushState' of undefined

My router code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import AppContainer from './components/AppContainer.jsx';
import MyTab from './components/test/MyTab.jsx';
import MainTab from './components/test/MainTab.jsx';


var routes = (
    <Route component={AppContainer} >
        <Route name="maintab" path="/" component={MainTab} />
        <Route name="mytab" path="/mytab" component={MyTab} />
    </Route>
);

React.render(<Router history={browserHistory}>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('main'));
```

The navigation button is on MyTab and it attemps to navigate to MainTab:

```
import React from 'react';
import 'datejs';
import History from "history";
export default React.createClass({

    mixins: [ History ],

    onChange(state) {
        this.setState(state);
    },

    handleClick() {
        this.history.pushState(null, `/`)
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container-fluid' >
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>TEST</button>
            </div>

        );
    }
});
```

When I use history with `this.props.history` everything works fine. What is the problem with this code?

**EDIT.**

After adding the following:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory();

React.render(<Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('main'));
```

I try to access my app. Before (without history={history}), I just accessed `localhost:8080/testapp` and everything worked fine - my static resources are generated into `dist/testapp` directory. Now under this URL I get:

> Location "/testapp/" did not match any resources

I tried to use the useBasename function in a following way:

```
    import { useBasename } from 'history'
    const history = useBasename(createBrowserHistory)({
    basename: '/testapp'
});

React.render(<Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('main'));
```

and the application is back, but again I get the error

> Cannot read property 'pushState' of undefined

in the call:

> ```
> handleClick() {
>     this.history.pushState(null, `/mytab`)
> },
> ```

I thougt it may be because of my connect task in gulp, so I have added history-api-fallback to configuration:

```
settings: {
      root: './dist/',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 8080,
      livereload: {
        port: 35929
      },
      middleware: function(connect, opt){
        return [historyApiFallback({})];
      }
    }
```

But after adding middleware all I get after accessing a website is:

> Cannot GET /

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of **"react-router": "^4.1.1"**, you may try the following:

Use '**this.props.history.push('/new-route')**'. Here's a detailed example

1: Index.js

```
 import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'; 
 //more imports here
    ReactDOM.render(
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
           <Switch>
              <Route path='/login' component={LoginScreen} />
              <Route path='/' component={WelcomeScreen} />
           </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
     </div>, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Above, we have used BrowserRouter, Route and Switch from 'react-router-dom'.

So whenever you add a component in the React Router 'Route', that is,

```
<Route path='/login' component={LoginScreen} />
```

..**then 'React Router' will add a new property named 'history' to this component** (LoginScreen, in this case).  You can use this history prop to programatically navigate to other rountes.

So now in the LoginScreen component you can navigate like this:

2: LoginScreen:

```
return (
      <div>
       <h1> Login </h1>
       <form onSubmit={this.formSubmit.bind(this)} >
         //your form here
       </form>
      </div>

    );



formSubmit(values) {
 // some form handling action
   this.props.history.push('/'); //navigating to Welcome Screen
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because everything changes like hell in react world here's a version which worked for me at December 2016:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, ReactRouter, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

var Main = require('../components/Main');
var Home = require('../components/Home');
var Dialogs = require('../components/Dialogs');

var routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Main}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path='/dialogs' component={Dialogs} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
);

module.exports = routes
```

Answer (score 1):

To create browser history you now need to create it from the `History` package much like you've tried.

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
```

and then pass it to the Router like so

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
    <Route />
</Router>
```

The [docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#histories) explain this perfectly

Comment: Please add those other history types createHashHistory, createBrowserHistory,createMemoryHistory

Comment: @limelights I tried your suggestion and updated the question. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: @holms It worked at the time of writing, react-router has undergone significant changes since january :)

Comment: Type 'History' is not assignable to type 'History'   --  **closes laptop**

Comment: Just tried this solution with React Router 4.1.1.  'history/lib/createBrowserHistory' wasn't working for me, but I was able to import 'history/createBrowserHistory'.

Comment: @ChrisNoreikis They probably changed it since a year ago. :)