# history is undefined in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, browser-history

I imported history like this.

```
import { Route , withRouter,history} from 'react-router-dom';
```

I am trying to use history like this

```
export const login = ( value, history ) => dispatch => { 
    //some code
    history.push('/dashboard');
  }
  else {
    //some code
  }
export default { login};
```

But I am getting error like below

```
TypeError: history is undefined
```

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be in that context?

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. Actually I got this solution from this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595890/react-router-undefined-history

Comment: That was written in the context of a class component, which you do not appear to have.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. Previously in another project I used `history.push('/dashboard');` and it was working. But in this project it is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Then give a [mcve] to show where you expect to be getting history from, but this definitely isn't going to work in an arrow function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. You can use this code `import Auth from '../../services/Auth';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import setAuthToken from '../../services/setAuthToken';
import { Route , withRouter,history} from 'react-router-dom';


export const login = ( value, history ) => dispatch => { 
    
  //some code
    history.push('/dashboard');};

export default { login};`

Comment: [Edit] the question, update the error, and explain where you think those arguments are going to come from.

Comment: So, again; *where do you think those arguments are going to come from?* This isn't a [mcve] until other people can recreate your issue.

Comment: @abuabu post `scr/pages/Login.js` contents here. Make sure this component receives `history` property from its parent, or better from `withRouter` HOC.

Answer (score 1):

Since `login` action creator is just a function (not a class nor bound one) `this` is not defined.

Try using an argument just as-is `history.push(...)`.

Comment: Thanks @amankkg. I am getting this error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIWff.png) if I use `history.push(...).`Thanks.

Comment: added a comment under your question. Anyway, there is a problem with `history` passing from the router to your component.

Answer (score 1):

Erase value, history and write props instead, might help as history is inside props

```
export const login = ( props ) => dispatch => {
```

Answer (score 0):

instead import history try

```
import {useHistory} from "react-router-dom";
let history=useHistory();
history.push("/");
```